# Nginx 404 Not Working, Redirects To Homepage

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to get a 404 error page to work if a file isn't found. Currently the server will just display the homepage instead of the 404 page. The rest of the site is behaving normally.

```
example.com/error-page/404.html // displays 404 page correctly.
```

I've tried adding the proxy_intercept_errors and fastcgi_intercept_errors directives with no luck.

Thanks for any help!

Config:

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    include snippets/ssl-example.com.conf;

    ssl on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.plygrid-LS-com.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.plygrid-LS-com.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/sites/example-com;

    server_name example.com;

    proxy_intercept_errors on;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    error_page 404 = /error-page/404.html;
    error_page 503 = /error-page/503.html;

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404 @extensionless-php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length  1100;
    gzip_buffers  4 32k;
    gzip_types        
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml;
    gzip_vary on;
}
```

Comment: Your configuration never generates a 404 response. If the URI does not exist, you try `URI.php`, and it that doesn't exist, you try `/index.php`.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix my issue by:

Adding an `index` to my main `try_files`:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404 @extensionless-php;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;
}
```

Removing `/index.php` from my php `try_files` and adding a `=404`:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/  =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

Adding a `rewrite` to trailing slashes on the php extension remover:

```
location @extensionless-php {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```